# SPARK 1.6 Insert into existing Hive table (non-partitioned)

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Given that I can get these singleton insert statements below to work as from another stack overflow question (thanks), then

```
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
  sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS e360_models.employee(id INT, name STRING, age INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")

   sqlContext.sql("insert into table e360_models.employee select t.* from (select 1210, 'rahul', 55) t")
   sqlContext.sql("insert into table e360_models.employee select t.* from (select 1211, 'sriram pv', 35) t")
   sqlContext.sql("insert into table e360_models.employee select t.* from (select 1212, 'gowri', 59) t")

   val result = sqlContext.sql("FROM e360_models.employee SELECT id, name, age")
   result.show()
```

what about if wanting to do an insert select from a SPARK DF registered as temporary table, to an already existing Hive table? I cannot seem to get it to work. Is it in fact possible?

Using 1.6 SPARK. Not interested in creating a table a la CTAS, but rather inserting to as per the above, but in bulk, e.g.

```
sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE default.ged_555 SELECT t.* FROM mytempTable t")
```

Comment: if you are not interested in CTAS pls see below approach.

Comment: It all works except that nothing is ever inserted, but no error.

Comment: Sorry! I havent seen this message.. before write.mode in below answer can you print df.show() so that data is present in df or not we can verify. if it is there it should insert too.

Comment: Since you are saying no error and no insert , I updated the code below please check. Also please add @myname to notify me otherwise I wont get notified. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understood you want to insert some data in to
>   ***`e360_models.employee`*** and then you want to select some columns and
>   again insert in to ***`default.ged_555`*** and also you don't want to do CTAS 
>   Prepare a dataframe from ***`e360_models.employee`*** and then do like below

```
// since you are using hive I used hiveContext below... 
 val dataframe = hiveContext.sql("select * from e360_models.employee ");

df.show(10) // to verify whether data is there in dataframe or not



df.printSchema(); // print schema as well for debug purpose.
    dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.OverWrite).insertInto("default.ged_555")

val sampleDataFrame = hiveContext.sql("select * from default.get_555");

// again do print 10 records to verify your result for debug purpose
sampleDataFrame.show()
// again print schema of the target table
sampleDataFrame.printSchema()
```

Comment: val dataframe = sqlContext.sql("select * from mytempTable");
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: mytempTable; line 1 pos 14

Comment: Am getting the above on cloudera VM quickstart, databricks seems better, not sure what to think

Comment: mytemptable is just an example. before that you need register that!

Comment: if I understood your requirement correctly, you dont want CTAS and you are looking for another approach. Question is bit not clear. can you elaborate pls? what is e360_models.employee & what is default.ged_555

Comment: Yes I had registered that but I think I am missing both SQL and Hive Context, may be a little error. Let me check

Comment: updated my answer. can you check and revert ? is that you are looking for ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127959/discussion-between-ramprasad-g-and-thebluephantom).

Comment: The issue is I cannot find my registered table, I just took a sampel working from DataBricks that works fine, but not a Cloudera VM.

Comment: Getting the error above. I will try to solve that and then check your input.

Comment: Disregard prior comment pls

Comment: All simpler with Spark 2.x